# Transferring Object over Sockets-Serializable

Tags: java, sockets, serialization

This is the code I've written to transfer an object pm(of class PM) which contains any objects vm(of class VM) over sockets.

```
public class PM implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID=1L;

    VM vm[]=new VM[10];

    //IP of the Agent
    String IP;

    public PM() {
        super();
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            vm[i]=new VM();}
        }
    }
```

VM is another class which has its own attributes.

```
public class VM implements Serializable{
       String osType;
}
```

The exchange of object pm over sockets takes place between 2 PCs . The server side receives the object from the client's side after the server has performed network discovery(hence the class names).

```
public class NetworkDiscovery extends TimerTask {
    InetAddress controllerIP;
    int controllerPort;
    static PM pm = new PM();

    NetworkDiscovery() throws UnknownHostException {
        controllerIP=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        controllerPort=4455;
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            byte[] recvBuf = new byte[5000];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(recvBuf, recvBuf.length);
            DatagramSocket dSock = new DatagramSocket(4445);
            dSock.receive(packet);
            int byteCount = packet.getLength();
            ByteArrayInputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(recvBuf);
            ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(byteStream));
            pm=(PM)is.readObject();
            System.out.println("object1" +pm.IP);
            is.close();
            dSock.close();
            System.out.println("object" + pm.vm[0].vmName);
        } //exceptions are caught etc.
    }
}
```

and on the client's side which sends the pm Object to server:

```
public class ackDiscovery extends TimerTask{
    int agentListenPort;
    InetAddress agentIP;
    ackDiscovery(Connect c) {
        agentListenPort=4445;
        c1=c;
    }
    public void run() {
        ObjectOutputStream os = null;
        try {
            PM pm = new PM();
            {
                pm.IP = InetAddress.getLocalHost().toString();
                pm.vm[i].osType = d1.getOSType();
                System.out.println("VMname" +i +pm.vm[i].osType);
                pm.vm[i].status = d1.isActive();
            }
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("Server_IP");
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(15000);
            os = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(byteStream));
            os.flush();
            os.writeObject((PM) pm);
            os.flush();
            byte[] sendBuf = byteStream.toByteArray();
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(sendBuf, sendBuf.length, address, 4445);
            int byteCount = packet.getLength();
            DatagramSocket dSock = new DatagramSocket();
            System.out.println("Quote of the Moment: " + pm.vm[0].osType);
            dSock.send(packet);
            os.close();
            dSock.close();
        } //exceptions caught etc.
    }
}
```

All the vm and pm details are getting populated on the client's side(I've checked it by printing them) . on the server's side, ONLY the pm details get populated on the local pm object after transfer. displaying the vm details on server side gives me null values.

My doubt:

1. Doesn't transferring an object which has children objects also, mean that the entire parent+child objects are transferred?
2. Do I have to manually transfer both vm and pm object separately?

Edit-

```
public class VM implements Serializable{
       String osType,vmName; //on server's side, these are still null
       int UUID,osVersion;   // on the server's side, these are 0. Are integer variables initialised to a default of zero?
       }
```

Comment: The objects that are held by the serialized object should be serialized as well and with it as long as they implement the Serializable interface (this should throw an exception if not) and they're not marked transient. Are you sure that the VM variable actually refers to a valid reference at the time you serialize the PM object?

Comment: Hm, it seems that you do check on my last question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels- Yes, I made class VM also implement Serializable . VM is valid because as soon as I populate vm object, I display the contents.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that after my first comment was locked. Looks like you're going to have to debug this further, perhaps by simplifying your code in an attempt to try to isolate the problem.

Comment: How do you you think I can do that? I've tested the populating and check if the client is sending it across. Also, I've checked that server indeed receives the latest copy. I also added other attributes to vm. I displayed all the vm attributes individually on server's side. While the string values are still NUll, the int values are 0(on the client's side it is 8). How is that?

Comment: @HovercraftFUllOfEels- Tried breaking the code into parts before executing them as a whole. Found no difference in output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are first-class objects in Java, they aren't serializable objects. There are three basic solutions to this problem:

Fields can be declared to be transient.
The writeObject( )/readObject( ) methods can be implemented.
serialPersistentFields can be declared.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

As @Hovercraft... mentioned, yes, `VM` should be serialized as well if the field is *not* marked `transient`.  `transient` ([definition](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Keywords/transient)) is the Java keyword that says that serialization should ignore that field.  If the `vm` field was marked as `transient` then it would always arrive as a `null` on the receiver.  In your case, the `vm` field should *not* use the transient keyword.

Not sure what the problem is but some things that I thought I'd comment on.

- Is is possible that you have a different version of your software on the different PCs?  Does the receiver have the `vm` field in `PM` for sure?
- It might be good to increment your `Serializable` id every time you change the class to make sure the `PM` class matches on client and server.  You can also remove the `serialVersionUID` and let the VM generated one ensure you have a matching class on both sides.  This will give an exception if they don't match.
- You probably know this but be careful that the `PM` size doesn't exceed a packet size since you are using `DatagramPacket`.  They can be fragmented, reordered, not delivered at all, etc..  I doubt `ObjectInputStream` would give you a partial object though.
- Make sure to catch exceptions and properly log the associated messages although you wouldn't get *any* objects if it was throwing.

Just for posterity, it is recommend to generate a `serialVersionUID` instead of relying on the VM's runtime calculation.  Whether or not you change the ID when you change your object depends on what sort of distributed system you are implementing.

Btw, the `serialVersionUID` is a per-class identifier that helps the Java VM verify that the class that was serialized matches the definition of the class being deserialized.  When an object is being deserialized, the VM looks up the object's class and makes sure the UID is the same.  If not then a `InvalidClassException` exception is thrown when the object is deserialized.  It doesn't matter if 2 different classes have the same UID.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Gray- as you said, 1. VM has been serialized. By transient, you mean that pm and vm object must be declared transient, right?(Tried it too but no change). 2. Both PCs have the same version of all the software. Since I'm unable to receive any vm details, how can I make sure that vm details are received at all? 3.Should I generate 2 UIDs for both VM and PM classes and see if they match? Thanks!

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide more details about transient.  Is the `vm` field null on the receiver?  I'd don't understand the "vm details" question.  I've added more details about the UIDs to my answer.  PM's and VM's UID are completely unrelated.  They can match or not but it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Gray- The vm field is null on the receiver.I've declared private static final long serialVersionUID=1L on both client and server sides. And about updating vm details,I don't know if it might help the discussion but I'm editing my question anyway.

Comment: Here's one thing to try @P Ramesh.  Log the _size_ of the packet on both the client and the server (`byteStream.size()` versus `recvBuf.size()`).  Make sure it matches.  Then add the `transient` keyword on *just* the client and make sure that the size goes down and is the same on the server.

Comment: You mention "I've declared private static final long serialVersionUID=1L on both client and server sides".  Just to be sure, you should be compiling your client and server programs using the *same* `PM` and `VM` class files.  You should not have separate classes in your client and server projects that you are trying to get to match.

Comment: @Gray- After trying out the serialVersionUID and checking in on the same versions of vm and pm classes,I checked out the buf size as per your instructions. EVERYTHING works fine! THANKS A TON!!! you're \m/